# tSQLt How can I tell if a table has been faked

Tags: sql, sql-server, unit-testing, ssms, tsqlt

I am just starting creating some unit tests for my database.

If I have faked a table,

```
EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable
    @TableName = 'dbo.[My Table]',
    @Identity = 0,
    @ComputedColumns = 0,
    @Defaults = 0
```

Can I check if it has been faked?

Note that documentation on the FakeTable SP can be found [here](http://tsqlt.org/user-guide/isolating-dependencies/faketable/).

**Motivation**

I want to be able to do this as I imagine creating several stored procedures which populate these faked tables so I can perform tests.
However I do not want to handle faking the tables in the stored procedures (so I can call them multiple times entering different info each time).

I don't want to have the possibility that I forget to fake the table before adding the data (as would almost certainly cause me to fail my test).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tSQLt adds an extended property to a fake table to track the table it fakes. This is easily tested using the function `tSQLt.Private_GetOriginalTableName`:

```
SELECT tSQLt.Private_GetOriginalTableName('dbo','[My Table]')
```

This will return `NULL` if the table isn't faked.

If you want to do something more complex, you can query `sys.extended_properties` directly. See the contents of the `tSQLt.class.sql`  script (in the [tSQLt distribution](http://tsqlt.org/downloads/)) for the definition of `tSQLt.Private_GetOriginalTableName`.

Comment: Face Palm.  Just recognized that tSQLt is a tool, and not the OP's typo....

Comment: Yeah sorry I could have made it more clear in my question that I was using a particular tool.

Comment: @Ed thanks, I'll do some testing in my code and mark this as accepted once I have got something working.

Comment: @Malrig Not your fault, all on me.

Answer (score -1):

You can check for the existence of the table at the beginning of your stored procedure(s).

```
If Not Exists ( Select 1 From Sys.Objects Where [Name] = 'YOURTABLENAME' And [Type] = 'U')
  Begin
  -- Your Create Table Statement Here
  ENd
```

Based on your comments, the tool has to be doing something like this, using schema:

```
Create table dbo.MisterPositive ( test int )
Create table developers.MisterPositive (test Int )

-- Both statements below work
Select * From dbo.MisterPositive
Select * From developers.MisterPositive
```

-- Use this to look for existence prior

```
Select 1 from sys.objects
  Inner join sys.schemas ON sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
 where sys.objects.[Name] = 'MisterPositive' And sys.schemas.name = 'dbo'

 Select 1 from sys.objects
  Inner join sys.schemas ON sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
 where sys.objects.[Name] = 'MisterPositive' And sys.schemas.name = 'Developers'
```

So yours would be

```
 If Not Exists ( Select 1 from sys.objects
  Inner join sys.schemas ON sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
 where sys.objects.[Name] = 'YOURTABLE' And sys.schemas.[Name] = 'tSQLt' )
   Begin
     -- create table here
   End
```

Comment: Does this specifically check if the table has been faked using tSQLt tools? Or just that a table exists?

Comment: If by faked, you mean does it exist in the database, then yes that is exactly what that statement does.  I don't know of a statement that will check by which method was a table created.  ( SSMS, or some other DBMS tool )

Comment: Ah then I don't think this works in this case. When I 'fake' a table I choose a table that already exists in the database and the tool sort of replaces it with an empty table of the same name (not sure how this works).
So the table already exists before I fake it.

Comment: Two tables with the same exact name cannot exist in any DBMS that I know of.  The only way around that would be using a different schema owner.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @Malrig I updated my answer so you can use your own code if you need too.  ( outside the tool )